# How to find() and filter() models for Ember.Select content

Tags: ember.js

I have a model which is many-to-many related to itself (depended objects). I want to use `Ember.Select` to set relatinships between objects. But not all objects may be ralted, so I need to filter them twice:

- has certain filed value
- id !== current object's id

Here is template:

```
{{view Em.Select     
    contentBinding="others"   
    multiple="true" }}
```

And here is <s>JS</s> CoffeeScript code:

```
App.Monster = DS.Model.extend
    location: DS.belongsTo('App.Location')
    requirements: DS.hasMany('App.Monster')


App.LessonEditController  = Em.ObjectController.extend
    ...
    others: (->
        _this = this
        App.Monster.find(location: this.get('model').get('location').get('id')).rejectProperty('id', this.get('model').get('id'))
        ).property()
```

Problems is that `find()` apperas to be lazy or something. It works only when i remove rejectProperty, so it's only one filtering. How to do both??